# Automate fortnite keys validation with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I'm attempting to automate the checking of Fortnite item codes. It involves pasting code by code and checking the message that appears. The issue is that when navigating with Selenium, I believe either Edge or the Fortnite page detects it, and when entering a code, there's no response. I'm not sure why this is happening or how to fix it.

This is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Edge
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service as EdgeService
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
import time

def leer_codigos(file):
    f = open(file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    codigos = []
    for line in lines:
        if ' ' not in line and len(line) > 1:
            codigos.append(line.split())
    return codigos

codigos = leer_codigos('codigos.txt')

print(codigos)

PATH_TO_EDGEDRIVER = r'C:\Users\maspi\Downloads\edgedriver_win64\msedgedriver.exe'

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36")

edge_service = EdgeService(PATH_TO_EDGEDRIVER)
driver = Edge(service=edge_service, options=options)
driver.get('https://store.epicgames.com/es-ES/redeem/fortnite')

driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.refresh()

try:
    for codigo in codigos:
        input_codigo = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'code'))
        )
        time.sleep(4)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1];", input_codigo, codigo)
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '';", input_codigo)

except Exception as e:
    print("Error al ingresar el código:", e)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

The first part simply reads 20-digit codes from a text file.